# Adding jQuery event listener for Google Translate

Tags: jquery, iframe, drop-down-menu, google-translate, jquery-events

I'd like to perform a jQuery function after someone translates my site into a different language using the [google translate dropdown](http://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en). Here's what I have tried with no luck:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
   $(".goog-te-menu-value").change(function() {
       alert("My code is working!");
   });
});
```

On a normal dropdown this would work fine, but I'm having trouble targeting the google translate div.. as I believe its in an iframe. Is there anyway to target a div that's in an iframe for use in jQuery? Or maybe another workaround? If anyone has any ideas on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but i have recently been working on this and it may help some one.

The problem with your code is you are binding your listener on the element that does not exists at the point of the document being ready & although the `.change()` method is technically a shortcut for `.on()` you have not gone high enough in the dom to allow for this 'future' addition to the dom.

so your code should be :

```
$('#google_translate_element').on('change','select.goog-te-combo',function(e){ console.log($(this).val()); /* or  alert($(this).val()); */ });
```

This will allow for the select box to have the change listener binded when it is added by google.

it works perfect on the site i am currently working.

Answer (score 0):

I too just added the Google Translate widget to my site and of course, it broke the layout!

So I reviewed the scripts used by the widget.

First, You cannot add an event listener to the button because the Google Translate widget already has one assigned.

Second, I discovered that after it translates, the GT widget sets the  tag to have a class.

So, I gave my  tag an id of "docstart" and created the following script.

**NOTE:** This breaks Firefox v. 21, but it works in IE 9.
I haven't tested it in any other browsers.

```
function LayoutFix() {
// code here to fix your layout
myListener();
};
function waitForGoogle() {
setTimeout (function myListener() {
var e = document.getElementById('docstart').className;
var l = e;
window.setInterval(function() {   
var cN = e.className;
if (cN !== l)
// Call function to fix the layout on class change
LayoutFix();
// Set a 10 second iteration
},10000);
// Set a 10 second wait for GT widget to load
},10000);
}
// Finally, load the listener on document.ready()
$(document).ready(waitForGoogle);
```